# Storing Image into database but facing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert image into database but when ever try to save image an exception occurs "Incorrect syntax near 'using'." Please guide.

My code is:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string InsertImage = "insert into Record(Name,Picture) using (@name,@img)";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertImage, MySQL);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text);
       int dataSize= FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
       byte[] ImgByte = new byte[dataSize];
       FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(ImgByte, 0, dataSize);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", ImgByte);
       if (MySQL.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       {
           MySQL.Open();
       }
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       MySQL.Close();
       Response.Write("Image has been stored");
   }
```

Comment: Which backend (Database) are you using? Insert statement used by you seems to have incorrect syntax.

Comment: using vs-2012. yes my insert quary was wrong. i was not using value keyword in my quary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definetly your syntax is incorrect. There is no **using** at *insert*, and for MySQL use **?** mark instead of **@** try this one:

```
string InsertImage = "insert into Record(Name,Picture) values(?name,?img)";
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", TextBox2.Text);
...
```

there is complete example at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with this statement

```
string InsertImage = "insert into Record(Name,Picture) values (@name,@img)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement is wrong. Try below statement:

```
string InsertImage = "insert into Record (Name,Picture) values (@name,@img)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying `insert into Record(Name,Picture) using (@name,@img)`?

try this simple insert query `insert into Record(Name,Picture) values(@name,@img)`